# Cloudinary file upload throws invalid URL for upload

Tags: python, heroku, flask, cloudinary

I am running an app on heroku using Flask and have been trying to use the Cloudinary add-on to make my image management a lot easier. The strange thing is that the api allows certain image files to pass with no hitch but other files raise an "Invalid URL for Upload" error.

Below is my code in routes.py:

```
@app.route("/cloudinary", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():

if 'email' not in session:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

user = User.query.filter_by(email = session['email']).first()

# Allows user to upload file into static folder
form = UploadForm()

if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.validate() == False:
        flash('All fields are required.')
        return render_template('upload.html', form=form, user = user)


    else: 
        file = request.files.get('photo') 
        if file:
            if user.usertype != 'Artist' and form.checkbox.data == False:
                flash('Sorry, only registered Artists can post pictures.')
                return render_template('upload.html', form=form, user = user)
            else:

                newpic = Picture(form.name.data, None, form.caption.data, user.id)
                #json_result = cloudinary.upload_image(file)
                #url = json_result.get('url')

                newpic.userid = user.id
                newpic.name = form.name.data
                json_result = cloudinary.upload_image(request.files['photo'], newpic.id)
                url = json_result.get('url')

                if form.checkbox.data == True:
                    user.profilepic = url
                    db.session.commit()

                newpic.filename = url
                newpic.caption = form.caption.data
                db.session.add(newpic)
                db.session.commit()
                return render_template('upload.html', form = form, success=True, user = user)

elif request.method == 'GET':
    filename = None
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form, filename=filename, user = user)
```

And here is the cloudinary class in models.py:

```
class Cloudinary(object):
  def __init__(self, app):
    config = app.config['CLOUDINARY_URL'].split('://')[1]
    config = config.replace("@", ":")
    self.api_key, self.api_secret, self.name = config.split(":")

  def upload_image(self, image, id):
    keys = {'public_id': id}
    res = uploader.call_api(
    "upload",
    uploader.build_upload_params(**keys),
    api_key=self.api_key,
    api_secret=self.api_secret,
    cloud_name=self.name,
    file=image.stream,
    )
    return res
```

Here's the log I get from Heroku throwing the 500 error:

```
2014-01-12T09:09:23.700352+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/cloudinary host=outlet-beta.herokuapp.com fwd="207.38.157.121" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=270ms status=500 bytes=291
```

Comment: While this is extremely old and probably no longer relevant, if you ever encounter similar issues, feel free to [directly contact Cloudinary](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) for resolution.